# Accept either comma separated values or newline separated values

Tags: javascript, csv, split

I have this code:

```
var skus = !input.match(/\,/) ? input.split('\n') : input.split(',');
```

This will get the contents of a `<textarea>` and depending on whether or not it contains commas, will return an array of items split by `\n` or `,`.  I don't believe this to be the best way to do it.

Before I just had :

```
var skus = input.split('\n') || input.split(',')
```

which was not giving me the result I wanted/expected. Is there a method/function/trick to accept either a list of CSV or new line separated values and split them by whichever the delimiter is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex in the split, like so:

```
'1,2\n3'.split(/[,\n]/)
```